# Setup Paypal client ID for credentials IOS SDK 2.1.6

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im using Paypal SDK in my app. I set my environment into PayPalEnvironmentSandbox but when I run my app theres an alert saying "There was a problem communicating with the Paypal servers. Please Try again". I googled a lot of times, other said that I need to change the clientId but i dont know how to change the client Id, I have a test account on sandbox in paypal but i dont know how to implement them in my app. I read the documentation and they said that I need to change may Client Id something like that but i dont know how. Need your help guys thank you. I am using iOS paypal SDK 2.1.6.

Code:

```
#import "ZZMainViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "PayPalMobile.h"

// Set the environment:
// - For live charges, use PayPalEnvironmentProduction (default).
// - To use the PayPal sandbox, use PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.
// - For testing, use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork.
//#define kPayPalEnvironment PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork
#define kPayPalEnvironment PayPalEnvironmentSandbox

@interface ZZMainViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *payNowButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *payFutureButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet UIView *successView;

@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PayPalConfiguration *payPalConfig;

@end

@implementation ZZMainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  // Set up payPalConfig
  _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
  _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
  _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";
  _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"Awesome Shirts, Inc.";
  _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
  _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];


  // Setting the languageOrLocale property is optional.
  //
  // If you do not set languageOrLocale, then the PayPalPaymentViewController will present
  // its user interface according to the device's current language setting.
  //
  // Setting languageOrLocale to a particular language (e.g., @"es" for Spanish) or
  // locale (e.g., @"es_MX" for Mexican Spanish) forces the PayPalPaymentViewController
  // to use that language/locale.
  //
  // For full details, including a list of available languages and locales, see PayPalPaymentViewController.h.

    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];


  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  self.successView.hidden = YES;



  // use default environment, should be Production in real life
  //self.environment = kPayPalEnvironment;
   //self.environment = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
  [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];
  NSLog(@"PayPal iOS SDK version: %@", [PayPalMobile libraryVersion]);
 [self pay];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];

  // Preconnect to PayPal early
  [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];
}

#pragma mark - Receive Single Payment

- (void)pay {
  // Remove our last completed payment, just for demo purposes.
  self.resultText = nil;

  // Note: For purposes of illustration, this example shows a payment that includes
  //       both payment details (subtotal, shipping, tax) and multiple items.
  //       You would only specify these if appropriate to your situation.
  //       Otherwise, you can leave payment.items and/or payment.paymentDetails nil,
  //       and simply set payment.amount to your total charge.

  // Optional: include multiple items
  PayPalItem *item1 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"Old jeans with holes"
                                  withQuantity:2
                                     withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"84.99"]
                                  withCurrency:@"USD"
                                       withSku:@"Hip-00037"];
  PayPalItem *item2 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"Free rainbow patch"
                                  withQuantity:1
                                     withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.00"]
                                  withCurrency:@"USD"
                                       withSku:@"Hip-00066"];
  PayPalItem *item3 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"Long-sleeve plaid shirt (mustache not included)"
                                  withQuantity:1
                                     withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"37.99"]
                                  withCurrency:@"USD"
                                       withSku:@"Hip-00291"];
  NSArray *items = @[item1, item2, item3];
  NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [PayPalItem totalPriceForItems:items];

  // Optional: include payment details
  NSDecimalNumber *shipping = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"5.99"];
  NSDecimalNumber *tax = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"2.50"];
  PayPalPaymentDetails *paymentDetails = [PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetailsWithSubtotal:subtotal
                                                                             withShipping:shipping
                                                                                  withTax:tax];

  NSDecimalNumber *total = [[subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping] decimalNumberByAdding:tax];

  PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
  payment.amount = total;
  payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
  payment.shortDescription = @"Hipster clothing";
  payment.items = items;  // if not including multiple items, then leave payment.items as nil
  payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil

  if (!payment.processable) {
    // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
    // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
    // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
    // to handle that here.
  }

  // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
  self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

  PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                              configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                   delegate:self];
  [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
  self.resultText = [completedPayment description];
  [self showSuccess];

  [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
  self.resultText = nil;
  self.successView.hidden = YES;
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
  // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
  NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
}


#pragma mark - Authorize Future Payments

- (IBAction)getUserAuthorization:(id)sender {

  PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *futurePaymentViewController = [[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController alloc] initWithConfiguration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];
  [self presentViewController:futurePaymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark PayPalFuturePaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalFuturePaymentViewController:(PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *)futurePaymentViewController didAuthorizeFuturePayment:(NSDictionary *)futurePaymentAuthorization {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Future Payment Authorization Success!");
  self.resultText = futurePaymentAuthorization[@"code"];
  [self showSuccess];

  [self sendAuthorizationToServer:futurePaymentAuthorization];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalFuturePaymentDidCancel:(PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *)futurePaymentViewController {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Future Payment Authorization Canceled");
  self.successView.hidden = YES;
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)sendAuthorizationToServer:(NSDictionary *)authorization {
  // TODO: Send authorization to server
  NSLog(@"Here is your authorization:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server to complete future payment setup.", authorization);
}


#pragma mark - Helpers

- (void)showSuccess {
  self.successView.hidden = NO;
  self.successView.alpha = 1.0f;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
  [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
  self.successView.alpha = 0.0f;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View Controller

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(ZZFlipsideViewController *)controller {
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  } else {
    [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
  }
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
  self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushSettings"]) {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
      UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
      self.flipsidePopoverController = popoverController;
      popoverController.delegate = self;
    }
  }
}

- (IBAction)togglePopover:(id)sender {
  if (self.flipsidePopoverController) {
    [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
  } else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender:sender];
  }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

To set your client IDs (one for Sandbox, one for Live), see step 1 in our [Sample Code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md#sample-code):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...
    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                     PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
  // ...
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @dave we are planning to use new paypal ios sdk for stuff like user will pay for some answers of his questions i.e. user has asked question and will pay some money through app if someone will answer that question. Payment will go thorough mediator i.e we would be taking money from user and than will pass money to who answered, will that pass APPLE review process ? can you please assist me further ?

Comment: @AniShroff I'm happy to help with technical issues involving our PayPal iOS SDK. But I can't advise you about Apple's app review process.

Comment: @DaveGoldman is there any way to get advise on this matter? I have tried searching web but could not get any details for this.

Comment: @Dave can I get the transaction key before paypal process the payment?

Comment: @AlvinJohnTandoc I'm not sure what you mean by "transaction key".

Comment: @Dave I think it's reference id or anything that will prove that I access paypal? Sorry I'm new to online payment.

Comment: @AlvinJohnTandoc [our documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md) covers the details of using the PayPal iOS SDK to process payments. I suggest that you start there to learn the necessary steps and terminology.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift development

```
    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction                             :@"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
      PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"ATIXyxAAjtL8-HdqfLq0kTCeefUi1SNI_xkfWktHelloqznRxsrm_Hello"}];
```

Will not work you need to do instead

```
 PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments([PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "ID1", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "ID2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a client_id you need to register & create an app at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps. You will then get sandbox (and live) credentials.

Comment: Im done with that sir but, I dont know how to change the client_id in the app.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change inside appdelegate.m file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary      *)launchOptions { #warning "Enter your credentials"
  [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction :    @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
  PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"ATIXyxAAjtL8-HdqfLq0kTCeefUi1SNI_xkfWktHelloqznRxsrm_Hello"}]; return YES;}
```